# Prevent editing/creating documents in list

Tags: 2010, web-part, permissions, list-form

I have a webpart from a child list on the parent display form, and this is the only area that I would like for users to add new items to the child list. Restricting permissions on the list to remove **edit/delete** from everyone wouldn't work because that would also affect their permissions on the web part of that list. Is there a way to hide the "new item" button only on the actual list?

If making the chrome type "`No Toolbar`" should remove this, it's not doing it. Here are the screenshots:

What I want hidden/disabled only on this webpart:

[image: New Item]

What I changed based on recommendation below:

[image: What I changed]

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are working on a SharePoint custom solution in Visual Studio. 
Add an empty element to your SharePoint solution. Add the following Xml to the Elements.xml file of the added element:

`<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
   <CustomAction RegistrationId="Your List Id Here" RegistrationType="List" Location="CommandUI.Ribbon" Id="HideRibbonButtons">
      <CommandUIExtension>
         <CommandUIDefinitions>
            <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListItem.New.NewListItem"/>
         </CommandUIDefinitions>
      </CommandUIExtension>
   </CustomAction>
</Elements>`

Make sure that the element is added to the feature and deploy.

Answer (score 1):

use this javascript to hide it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var elem = document.getElementById("Ribbon.ListItem.New-LargeLarge");
elem.style.display = "none";
</script>
```

Comment: even admin wont see that.did u saved the changes properly? try it once again.and see what Toolbar type contains

Comment: I just refreshed and the list web part still says "Toolbar Type: No Toolbar"

Comment: did u pressed stop edit on page?

Comment: Yes, and I refreshed a few times.

Comment: can you just put the screen shots to know your problem exactly

Comment: I have added two.

Comment: Is this what you were talking about?

Comment: just see my updated ans